# Testing an async method that uses SemaphoneSlim internally to achieve parallelisation

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, async-await, semaphore

I wrote an extension method for `IEnumerable<Uri>` to allow downloading the resources specified in the URIs. This is the simplified code:

```cs
public static async Task DownloadInParallel(this IEnumerable<Uri> values, HttpClient httpClient, Func<Uri, int, Stream, Task> successCallback, int maxDownloadsInParallel, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: maxDownloadsInParallel);

    var tasks = values.Select(async (x, i) =>
    {
        await throttler.WaitAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        try
        {
            using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(x, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
            using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                await successCallback(x, i, stream).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            throttler.Release();
        }
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Writing unit tests using a mock `HttpMessageHandler` to assert the execution of the success callback is straight-forward, but it is not good enough in my view because the fundamental functionality provided by the extension method is not just that the list of resources are downloaded, but the ability to execute those downloads in parallel, up to the specified limit. However, this is difficult to test as there is no visibility of when a thread enters the semaphore. This means that I can't do assertions related to parallelism, which has two aspects: that downloads were indeed executed in parallel and not sequentially, and also that the degree of parallelism went up to, but didn't exceed, the specified limit.

As a workaround, I thought of adding events to the containing class which would be invoked when the semaphore is entered and released. These would not be exposed in the release build by using conditional compilation via preprocessor directives and making them internal and using `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`.

```cs
#if TEST
internal static event EventHandler SemaphoreEnter;
internal static event EventHandler SemaphoreRelease;
#endif

public static async Task DownloadInParallel(this IEnumerable<Uri> values, HttpClient httpClient, Func<Uri, int, Stream, Task> successCallback, int maxDownloadsInParallel, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: maxDownloadsInParallel);

    var tasks = values.Select(async (x, i) =>
    {
        await throttler.WaitAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
#if TEST
        SemaphoreEnter?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
#endif
        try
        {
            ...
        }
        finally
        {
            throttler.Release();
#if TEST
            SemaphoreRelease?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
#endif
        }
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

This allows me to build a sequence of events that were invoked so that I can do my assertions. While it works, it feels like a hacky solution. Is this reasonable? What other methods can I employ to test this core functionality? Are there other threading constructs that are better suited?

Comment: Is it an option to split the `DownloadInParallel` into two methods, one that contains only the parallelization functionality (similar to the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-6.0)), and one that is built on top of the first and adds the download functionality?

Comment: You should put your test code inside the mock.

Comment: So there are 2 ways i would do it: 1. If you have VS enterprise, use Microsoft Fakes (that is now compatible with .net core) and just Shim the stuff out of APIs to just assert on calls. 2. In absence of fakes, i would set up my UT to start a local webserver (e.g. Kestrel) on a random free port and have that respond to URIs with {id}, waiting for say 300 ms and then returning something. When a request is received, that'd capture the timestamp. I'd then run your code against URIs of my local server and assert that only X are received within 300 ms of each other, and that total number matched

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, that would just move the problem into a second method, no? The semaphore is not exposed so its functionality will always be hidden to the outside.

Comment: @PauloMorgado, I don't understand what you mean. I have a mock `HttpMessageHandler` I'm passing to the constructor of `HttpClient`. I'm not aware of any hooks that I can use to figure out a download starting.

Comment: @zaitsman, I'm using Community edition. Your suggestion with Kestrel could work, but I think it's too much for what is supposed to be a unit test. Also, it seems like it's just another workaround, and swapping one workaround with a different, more complex workaround isn't appealing.

Comment: @Moss the problem with what you proposed (e.g. events) is that if someone modifies your code to emit them at wrong places your UT may pass but runtime behaviour will be broken. Running this against some API actual tests that code-under-test does what you want from it. It's a grey area re: nomenclature (whether you'd consider it a 'unit' test) but it's a harness that will guarantee you will find out changes in behaviour in CI/local run not after you deployed your code.

Comment: The [`HttpMessageHandler` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler) has a [`HttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage, CancellationToken)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler.sendasync#System_Net_Http_HttpMessageHandler_SendAsync_System_Net_Http_HttpRequestMessage_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) that is invoked by the `HttpClient`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so focused on getting this working with threading specific components, I overlooked the simple answer.

What I had in my tests was:

```cs
HttpHandlerMock.Protected()
               .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(...)
               .ReturnsAsync(...);
```

Took Paolo's comment on board and changed the code to the following by adding the `Callback` method, which allowed me to do the desired assertions on the `Events` collection.

```cs
HttpHandlerMock.Protected()
               .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(...)
               .Callback(() => Events.Add("start"))
               .ReturnsAsync(...);
```